# ¿Cómo hacer que el dominio y el index.php sean la misma página y no se dupliquen?

Tags: php, seo

¿Cómo se debe hacer para que no se dupliquen el dominio y el index.php?
Me sucede que a pesar de ser una sola web, parece que para google son 2 páginas. www.ejemplo.com y www.ejemplo.com/index.php

¿Cómo se debe solucionar esto? ¿Afecta al SEO?

Comment: Puedes intentar esto en el `.htaccess` del root de tu dominio: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>` es el código que se usa en los sitios que usan WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar agregar la url canónica de tu sitio web en el head del HTML.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="www.ejemplo.com"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**¿Qué es la etiqueta canónica?**

La etiqueta canonical, conocida en inglés como Canonical Tag, se sitúa en el código fuente de un sitio web y apunta a las URLs canónicas que muestran el mismo contenido, o contenido muy similar. Si se indica cuál es la URL canónica correctamente, esta será utilizada para la indexación de los motores de búsqueda.

Los buscadores puntúan negativamente a los sitios web que presentan contenido duplicado porque no ofrecen valor añadido para los usuarios. Se recomienda utilizar la etiqueta canonical para no ser penalizados por contenido duplicado y usar herramientas como, por ejemplo, el Duplicate Content Checker que te ayuda a reconocer este tipo de contenido.

https://es.ryte.com/wiki/Etiqueta_Rel%3DCanonical